# Script folder missing when load extension on VSTS and TFS 2017

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have an extension works fine on my TFS server (2015 update 3). After upgrade the server to TFS 2017 (Version 15.112.26301.0), the extension seems broken. Our extension provide 2 dashboard widgets. In the vss-extension.json, we tell:
[image]

While load my widget from dashboard, it always complain all my js file are missing. It seems the entrie "script" folder is not loaded correct:
[image]

Anyone can help on this issue? Inside my extension vsix file, everything is there:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried removing and then reinstalling the extension?

Answer (score 0):

Give a try with update the extension by update version number in `vss-extension.json`  . Take a look at this issue: [TFS 2017 Widget : widget failed to load](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/99898adf-8d13-43b3-bc68-4ff36c1d7ce3/tfs-2017-widget-widget-failed-to-load?forum=tfsreporting)